# Flutter: How Can I Add buttons to Local Notification

Tags: dart, flutter, localnotification

i've been able to show Local Notification but is there any option to show buttons below the notification?

(See "Snooze" & "Dismiss" button in the attached picture).

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code for showing local notification?

Comment: Checkout this medium post might be helpful for you https://medium.com/@info_67212/firebase-push-notification-with-action-button-in-flutter-a841da348097

Comment: Late but checkout this plugin
https://github.com/mitchhymel/local_notifications

Answer (score 3):

If you are using [local_notifications](https://github.com/mitchhymel/local_notifications) you can add `actions`:

```
handleCustomActionClick(String payload) {
    if(payload == "secondAction") {
        LocalNotifications.removeNotification(0);
    }
}

int id = await LocalNotifications.createNotification(
    title: "Multiple Actions",
    content: 'With custom callbacks',
    id: 0,
    onNotificationClick: new NotificationAction(
        actionText: "Some action",
        callback: onNotificationClick,
        payload: "Some payload",
        launchesApp: false
    ),
    actions: [
        new NotificationAction(
            actionText: "First",
            callback: handleCustomActionClick,
            payload: "firstAction",
            launchesApp: true
        ),
        new NotificationAction(
            actionText: "Second",
            callback: handleCustomActionClick,
            payload: "secondAction",
            launchesApp: false
        )
    ]
);
```