# Add buttons in a local notification in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-local-notification

I am using the local notification package and I need to add buttons to notification. How to add these buttons to a notification.

```
Future<void> showDailyAtTime() async {
    var time = Time(20, 3, 0);
    var androidChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'CHANNEL_ID 4',
      'CHANNEL_NAME 4',
      "CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION 4",
      importance: Importance.Max,
      priority: Priority.High,
    );
    var iosChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannelSpecifics =
    NotificationDetails(androidChannelSpecifics, iosChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.showDailyAtTime(
      0,
      'Test Title at ${time.hour}:${time.minute}.${time.second}',
      'Test Body', //null
      time,
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      payload: 'Test Payload',
    );
  }
```

this is the function which iam using to show notification

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: How Can I Add buttons to Local Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52408222/flutter-how-can-i-add-buttons-to-local-notification)

Comment: yes, I want to like this pic in this question, but I can't use this code with my code. actually, i can't understand this code

Comment: I think he creates something like local notification from first

Comment: Yes, he's using LocalNotifications to create and show the notification, the 'actions' list represents the buttons that are displayed in the notification, those buttons will have the text 'First' and 'Second' and they also have ids 'firstAction', and 'secondAction' in order to differentiate them when the user clicks on one of the buttons, and the function 'handleCustomActionClick' is called (you can see that it is set as a callback).

Comment: how to add this in my code. if i put this code gives me error because he use localNotifications as a class not package as i use

Comment: by this way i should delete what is done ? and create the new project with this code?